# Ava test setTimeout() on addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, settimeout, jsdom, ava

I have this function which I want to test with `ava` and `browser-env`

```
function foo () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('pushcommand', { detail: 'foo', bubbles: true })
    document.getElementById('command-history').dispatchEvent(event)
  }, 1)
}
```

My test code is:

```
import test from 'ava'
import foo from 'foo.js'

test('foo', t => {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<ul id="command-history"></ul>'
  document.getElementById('command-history').addEventListener('pushcommand', event => {
    t.is(event.detail, 'foo')
  })
  foo()
})
```

But I get the error in `ava`: `Error: Test finished without running any assertions`.
The code from the event listener is executed, it's just that ava doesn't reach it before exiting the test.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

I tried `test.serial`, `async await`, `t.end()` to no avail. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async-await can be tricky. the test is probably ending before the async callback is called. since no promise is returned (async) ava doesn't know to wait until the test is complete. something like this should help communicate to ava to wait until the promise finishes

```
import test from 'ava'
import foo from 'foo.js'

function foo () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('pushcommand', { detail: 'foo', bubbles: true })
    document.getElementById('command-history').dispatchEvent(event)
  }, 1)
}

test('foo', async (t) => {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<ul id="command-history"></ul>'
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.addEventListener('error', reject)
    document.getElementById('command-history').addEventListener('pushcommand', event => {
      t.is(event.detail, 'foo')
      resolve()
    })
    foo()
  })
})
```

Comment: It's working thanks. Although the `window.addEventListener('error', reject)` code is not actually doing anything. I have added `throw new Error('error')` in `foo()` and `ava` would not pick it up.

Comment: Also `test.serial(...)` is needed if you make more than one tests in one file, because when in paralel (default), the event listener jumps from one value to another.

Comment: should be easy enough to use different / random event names for each test if you want parallel. just use the beforeeach hook. if you'd like an explaination feel free to create a new question

Comment: window.addEventListener('error', (e) => console.error('erred in handler', e))
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => { throw new Error('erred in body handler')})

this works when you click on the body. but that may just be a limitation of the packages you're using